# new content don't match

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I'm loading some content via AJAX and trying to add some functionality,
I have this code to show/hide some content:

```
$('.list li').hover(
            function() { $('.detail').show(); }, 
            function() { $('.detail').hide(); }
        );
```

This works fine on first load, but when in load more content via AJAX not work.
Any Ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.on` you can delegate the event to the `.list` element, so that adding new `li` elements will not break the intended functionality.

```
$(".list").on("mouseenter mouseleave", "li", function(e){
    $(".detail").toggle( e.type === "mouseenter" );
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NGEfj/

If the `.detail` element is within the `li`, and not on its own somewhere else in the page:

```
$(".list").on("mouseenter mouseleave", "li", function(e){
    $(".detail", this).toggle( e.type === "mouseenter" );
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NGEfj/1/

Answer (score 2):

`$('.list')` only constructs a list of the currently present '.list' items.

You must use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to add event handlers to elements that aren't yet present.

You can do this :

```
$('body').on('mousenter', '.list li', function({ $('.detail').show()});
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.list li', function({ $('.detail').hide()});
```

Comment: sorry, I miss to add li to my selector

Comment: Are you adding other `li` in your `.list`, or are you adding other `.list` to your body ? Both are easy to manage but are done a little differently.